# Showing an ArrayList content on a Toast

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, arraylist, toast

I have a listView and I want to print the arrrayList which contains the selected items.

I can show the choice that I choose every time. i.e. if I select a choice, I can print it in a toast (I mark it in my code as a comment), but I want to print the whole choices together.
Any help please?

Thanks..

Comment: why you removed your previously posted code?

Comment: @donfuxx If you need it it is exist in the answers below

Comment: I don't understand why you removed the code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to display the contents of your arrayList in a Toast.

1. Like donfuxx said, you need to create your arrayList outside of your onclicklistener.
2. As the user clicks an item, it will be added to your arrayList.
3. Then loop over the list to fill a string called allItems, then show allItems in a toast.

   ```
   ArrayList<String> checked = new ArrayList<String>();

   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
               int position, long id) {

           String listItem = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

           if(!checked.contains(listItem)){ //optional: avoids duplicate Strings in your list
               checked.add((position+1), listItem);
           }
           String allItems = ""; //used to display in the toast

           for(String str : checked){
             allItems = allItems + "\n" + str; //adds a new line between items
           }

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),allItems, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: You should also make sure that you avoid an IndexOutofBoundsException as you add items at positions that might not exist in your ArrayList. Consider using checked.add(listItem) instead of checked.add((position+1), listItem);

Answer (score 1):

Well you have the right concept, jsut wrong execution here is the part you missed out on:`

```
ArrayList<String> checked = new ArrayList<String>();
checked.add((position+1), listItem);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),checked.get((position+1)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
```

You have to get the position of the element in the ArrayList which you require to fetch, hence 
`checked.get(array position of element here)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show every item that is in the ArrayList you can use a simple loop and add them to a string like this:

```
...
checked.add((position+1), listItem);

String tempString = "";
for(int x = 0; x < checked.length(); x++) {
    tempString = tempString + ", " + checked.get(x);
}
tempString = tempString.substring(2);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tempString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**EDIT** modified it a bit to only put commas between items

Comment: But I need the array to use it somewhere else.

Comment: this doesnt get rid of the array so you can use it other places. If you want all the contents in a string again just run the loop again or make a function that will return the string.

Comment: The Toast does not appear

Comment: Well that's a separate issue altogether. Toast messages are not supposed to be that long so if your array is going to have a lot of items you might want to use an alert dialog instead. If you are just using Toast to debug you should use Log. Otherwise I''m not sure, maybe try using `YOURACTIVITYNAME.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: I have only 2 items. so toast is suitable I think

Comment: how to use Log? I don't know. Could you please help me?

Comment: Check this page for info on using Log: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: In the example above you could just use `Log.i("tag",tempString);` instead of the toast. Then check the Logcat for the message. Users will not see this though, so it is mainly used for debugging.