# Retrofit Recycler view from MYSQL PHP Slim

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to learn how to load my recycler view from mySQL.  Followed a few tutorials but the recycler view shows up but doesn't fill with anything.  So I'm not sure what I did wrong.
What I'm trying to do is I have one app that allows me to take pictures and send some input to my xammp server.  Then this app will let you use a recycler view to view the picture and some textfields, eventually being able to click them to get more info.  Eventually I want to turn this into an app of some kind I give to local animal shelter or something.  They take a picture of their dogs on one app, and then people can download the other app and see the dogs available.

Now I know the image stuff is messed up so I noted it out.  My "url" is my path on my server not a http url, I haven't figured out how to get that to work yet I know it won't work with picasso(I thought it would, I'm kinda new to this), still learning that's why that picasso stuff is there.

TL;DR
But I can't get the recyclerview to show any data on the page aka firsname, lastname.

Here is my index.php

```
$app->get('/getprofilepic', function(request $request, Response $response){

$db = new profilepic; 
$profiledata = $db->getprofilepic();
$response->getBody()>write(json_encode(array("profiledata"=>$profiledata)));
});
```

here is my php profilepic

```
     private $con; 

     function __construct(){

        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
        $db = new DbConnect; 
        $this->con = $db->connect(); 
    }

public function getprofilepic(){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT doginfohometab1db.ID, doginfohometab1db.firstnametxt, doginfohometab1db.lastnametxt, profilepicdb.picurl FROM doginfohometab1db LEFT JOIN profilepicdb ON doginfohometab1db.ID = profilepicdb.ID  WHERE doginfohometab1db.ID in(SELECT ID FROM doginfohometab1db WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM dogdischargeinfohometab1db WHERE doginfohometab1db.id = dogdischargeinfohometab1db.id))");
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result($ID, $firstnametxt, $lastnametxt, $picurl);
        $profiledata = array();             
        while($stmt->fetch()){ 
        $temp = array(); 
    $temp ['ID'] = $ID;
    $temp ['firstnametxt'] = $firstnametxt; 
    $temp ['lastnametxt'] = $lastnametxt; 
    $temp ['picurl'] = $picurl;
    array_push($profiledata, $temp);
        }
        return $profiledata; 
    }
}
```

This is my postman response

```
{"profiledata":
```

[{"ID":"hvg766khhv","firstnametxt":"hvg","lastnametxt":"khhv","picurl":"C:\xampp\htdocs\pathways1\includes/uploads/1535685930271.jpg"},{"ID":"jdjd676jdjf","firstnametxt":"jdjd","lastnametxt":"jdjf","picurl":"C:\xapp\htdocs\pathways1\includes/uploads/1535686965814.jpg"}]}

here is my api call

```
@GET("getprofilepic")
Call<PtList> PtList();
```

PtList class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class PtList {

@SerializedName("ptList")
private ArrayList<dogdata> ptList;

public ArrayList<dogdata> getdogArrayList(){
    return ptList;
}

public void setdogArrayList(ArrayList<dogdata> dogArrayList){
    this.ptList = dogArrayList;
}
}
```

this is my dogdata class

```
public class dogdata {
@SerializedName("firstnametxt")
private String firstnametxt;
@SerializedName("lastnametxt")
private String lastnametxt;
@SerializedName("ID")
private String ID;

private boolean isSelected = false;
@SerializedName("picurl")
private String picurl;

dogdata(String firstnametxt, String lastnametxt, String ID, String picurl){

    this.ID = ID;
    this.firstnametxt = firstnametxt;
    this.lastnametxt = lastnametxt;
    this.picurl = picurl;
}

public String getID(){
    return ID;
}

public void setID(String ID){
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String getPicurl(){
    return picurl;
}

public void setPicurl (String picurl){
    this.picurl = picurl;
}

public String getFirstnametxt(){
    return firstnametxt;
}

public void setFirstnametxt(String firstnametxt){
    this.firstnametxt = firstnametxt;
}

public String getLastnametxt(){
    return lastnametxt;
}

public void setLastnametxt(String lastnametxt){
    this.lastnametxt = lastnametxt;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    isSelected = selected;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}
}
```

this my activity class

```
 public class TreatmentMain extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private RecyclerView mptRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mptAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_treatment_main);

    downdogdata();
}

private void generatePtList(ArrayList<dogdata> ptList){
    mptRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ptrecycler_view);
    mptAdapter = new TreatmentAdapter(this, ptList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager ptmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(TreatmentMain.this);
    mptRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mptRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(ptmanager);
    mptRecyclerView.setAdapter(mptAdapter);
}

public void downdogdata() {

    Call<PtList> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getAPIService().PtList();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<PtList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PtList> call, Response<PtList> response) {

            if (response.code() == 200) {
              generatePtList(response.body().getdogArrayList());
            }
            else if (response.code() == 422)
                Toast.makeText(TreatmentMain.this, "Opps your code don't work bro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            {
            } }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PtList> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(TreatmentMain.this, "Opps your code don't work bro on failure toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.txmainback:
            Intent txmainback = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(txmainback);
    }
}
}
```

and lastly my adapter class

```
 public class TreatmentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TreatmentAdapter.MyptViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<dogdata> mptModelList;

private myptAdapterListener mptListener;
String ID;
Context mptcontext;
public interface myptAdapterListener{
    void ontextClick(int position);
}

public TreatmentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<dogdata> mptModelList) {
    this.mptModelList = mptModelList;
    mptcontext = context;
}

@Override
public MyptViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.treatmentrow, parent, false);
    return new MyptViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyptViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final dogdata ptmodel = mptModelList.get(position);
    holder.Treatmentfirstname.setText(ptmodel.getFirstnametxt());
    holder.Treatmentlastname.setText(ptmodel.getLastnametxt());
 //   Picasso.get().load(ptmodel.getPicurl()).fit().centerCrop().error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground).into(holder.ptreatmentprofile);
    ID = ptmodel.getID();

    holder.view.setBackgroundColor(ptmodel.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN: Color.WHITE);
    holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ptmodel.setSelected(!ptmodel.isSelected());
            holder.view.setBackgroundColor(ptmodel.isSelected() ? Color.GREEN : Color.WHITE);
            mptListener.ontextClick(position);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mptModelList == null ? 0 : mptModelList.size();
}

public class MyptViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private View view;
    private TextView Treatmentfirstname;
    private TextView Treatmentlastname;
    private ImageView ptreatmentprofile;

    public MyptViewHolder(final View View) {
        super(View);
        view = View;
       Treatmentfirstname = (TextView) View.findViewById(R.id.Treatmentfirstname);
       Treatmentlastname =(TextView) View.findViewById(R.id.Treatmentlastname);
       ptreatmentprofile = (ImageView) View.findViewById(R.id.ptreatmentprofile);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of code to cover here and your question is not well defined. You show us the postman response, but have not indicated whether you were able to get the same data downloaded with your app. Have you even checked to see if your `ArrayList` has any data? --- Also please learn java naming convention. It will serve you well. Variables in java are not capitalized and camel case is used throughout so that  "Treatmentfirstname" should be "treatmentFirstName"; and this `MyptViewHolder(final View View)` is just painful and then this? `view = View;` why?

Comment: man youtube videos and tutorials don't cover such things as naming convention.  I know you may have learned that in your fancy classes and what not, but those of us learning on the web simply don't see that subject covered.  We just trying to learn.  Which is what this site is for.   I have tried to toast ptList from this method. private void generatePtList(ArrayList<dogdata> ptList) above but it just crashes.  Using this way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636941/showing-an-arraylist-content-on-a-toast.  both my other Recycler views use List<> not ArrayList<>. and my learning of cont..

Comment: retrofit, I have never had to pull down more than 1 variable at a time for a log in or what ever not an array.  they look more like user.getName(),.  which you would see in the the adapter.

Comment: Take it easy gtcode -- No offense was intended. All my comments were very neutral in tone. I don't see how saying "please learn.." can put you into such a testy mood. Sadly, you haven't responded to any of the questions I posed in my comment. Just a final tip for the future (since you are just starting to learn) -- It is always best to start with small chunks of code and test each section, . making certain each method returns the data you expect before moving on to add more code..particularly if you don't quite understand how it work.

Comment: I figured it out finally.  I'm out to figure out how to get my picture to load without a webURL.